# Basic Html.ValidationMessageFor not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have a simple feedback form on our website. When users enter html in the page, they should get a validation error message. But they don't. The exception is thrown and caught in:

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ...
}
```

The exception caught here is:

> A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the
>   client
>
> at System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateString(String value, String
>   collectionKey, RequestValidationSource requestCollection)

Here is the Asp.net MVC markup:

```
<form action="<%=Url.Action("Create") %>" method="post" class="data-entry-form">
<fieldset class="comment">
    Your thoughts:
    <div class="editor-field">
        <%= Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Comment, 10, 2, new { placeholder="your message" }) %> 
        <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Comment) %>
    </div>
    <br />

    E-mail address (optional)
      <div class="editor-field">                        
          <%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email, new { placeholder="you@youremailaddress.com" }) %>
          <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email) %>
      </div>
          <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</fieldset>
</form>
```

and here is the generated html:

```
    <form action="/feedback/Create/" method="post" class="data-entry-form">
    <fieldset class="comment">
        Your thoughts:
        <div class="editor-field">
            <textarea cols="2" id="Comment" name="Comment" placeholder="your message" rows="10">
            </textarea> 
        </div>
        <br />

        E-mail address (optional)
        <div class="editor-field">                        
           <input id="Email" name="Email" placeholder="you@youremailaddress.com" type="text" value="" />                  
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Send" />
    </fieldset>
    </form>
```

And here is the controller code:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Feedback feedback)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        FillFeedbackObject(feedback);
        feedbackRepository.AddFeedback(feedback);
        return View("SuccessMessage", new SuccessMessageModel("Thanks for your message!"));
    }
    return View(feedback);
}
```

I also have `<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />` in the appSettings section of the web.config file and I am including jquery.validate.js. So both client side and server side validation fail.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, leaving request validation in place has it's advantages, and you're correct disabling request validation shouldn't be taken lightly. But there's no graceful way to handle this exception in ASP.NET because it happens so early in the pipeline. It's the actual framework protecting you from yourself.

You can use the `Application_Error` event that you pointed out in your original post. The come up with some code like:

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var exception = Server.GetLastError();
    if (exception is HttpRequestValidationException)
    {
        // use Response.Redirect to get the user back to the page, and use session/querystring to display an error
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks. How do I Response.Redirect to the page that was displayed before the exception was thrown from Application_Error?

Comment: @user277498 [`Request.Url`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.url(v=vs.110).aspx) should have all the information you need to see what page was being requested when the exception was encountered.

Comment: Thanks Steven ! How do I communicate with the original page that there is an error with the text, so a validation message is shown?

Comment: @user277498 You can set it to `Session` from there, or you can use a querystring like `example.aspx?error=1` and have the page check `Session` or the query string when it loads.

Comment: Thanks for being so helpful. This all works fine except the original message that the user entered will be gone and they will have to reenter it. I am still wondering if there is a better way to do all this. And this is something every website has to deal with. So I am surprised there is no baked in mechanism for it.

Answer (score 2):

It's not technically a Model's error, that's why you cannot handle it with `Model.IsValid` code statement.

If you actually allow html to be submitted in this field or want to sanitize submitted value on server you may annotate`Comment` property of your model with [[AllowHtml]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.allowhtmlattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) attribute. Also, if you want to notify user that they cannot include tags in the text, you may add an error to `ModelState` during feedback parsing on server side with [ModelState.AddModelError()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelstatedictionary.addmodelerror%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) method.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the `[ValidateInput(false)]` attribute to your controller action method.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.validateinputattribute.aspx

**Edit:** If you still want to validate, you should encode the input before sending to the server, for example using `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode`. The reason the validation blocks the code is because it could be malicious. By encoding it you can allow it to pass through and still have validation enabled. However you may need to change your validation rules/attributes to account for the encoding. In case it wasn't clear before, this option requires validating on the server side once you get to the controller, adding an error to the ModelState as needed, and returning the same view or partial view as needed in case of errors.

Comment: Thanks, that turns off validation. I want validation to work. I want the user to get a message that their input is not valid. I do not want to allow their input to go in, nor do I want a global exception to be thrown.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to html encode the messages. I just want to prompt the user that the entry is not valid and have them fix it.

Comment: The point was to encode them so that they could get to the controller for you to add an error to the ModelState and return the view with a validation error. This would achieve what you want, but it's server-side. If you want to do it with client-side validation, you need to write something custom using Javascript or JQuery, or (a more practical option) add a custom rule using the JQuery Validate plugin.

Answer (score 0):

With MVC 3 and above you can use the AllowHtml attribute with the property that can contain some html

Comment: I do not want to allow html, I just want to notify the user that their input is not accepted and prompt them to re-enter it.