# rejecting html entered in form gracefully in asp.net MVC and via jQuery Validate

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate

If the user enters HTML in a form TextArea, the entry should not be allowed. There should be client side and server side validation. The entry including html should be rejected and the user should be notified with an appropriate message. How do we do this?

Note: This is a followup to the question I asked here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20499955/basic-html-validationmessagefor-not-working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20499955/basic-html-validationm). Thanks to all those who answered and helped with this answer. Better answers are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since entering html in a TextArea results in an HttpRequestValidationException exception being thrown, early in the pipeline, we can only catch it along with unhandled exceptions in Global.asax.

In Global.asax.cs we add:

```
        void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();
            ex = ex.InnerException ?? ex;
            if (ex is HttpRequestValidationException)
            {
                string url = Request.Url.ToString() + "?error=1";
                Response.Redirect(url);
                Server.ClearError();               
                return;
            }
            //any other exception handling that you need goes here
       }
```

Here is the markup:

```
<form action="<%=Url.Action("Create") %>" method="post" class="data-entry-form" id="feedBackForm">
<fieldset class="comment">

    <div class="editor-field">
        <%= Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Comment, 10, 2, new { placeholder="your message" }) %> 
        <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Comment) %>
        <% if (Request.QueryString["error"] == "1")
           {
               Response.Write("<br/><span class= 'error'>Please remove all HTML from your comment and resubmit</span>");
           } %></div>
    <br />

    E-mail address (optional)
      <div class="editor-field">                        
          <%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email, new { placeholder="you@youremailaddress.com" }) %>
          <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email) %>
      </div>
          <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</fieldset>
</form>
```

notice the line: `if (Request.QueryString["error"] == "1"` handles the parameter passed in the redirect in Application_error

So far we have server side validation.

For client side validation, we add a custom rule using the JQuery Validate plugin:

```
    jQuery.validator.addMethod("hasNoHTML", function (value, element) {
        if (value.match(/<(\w+)((?:\s+\w+(?:\s*=\s*(?:(?:"[^"]*")|(?:'[^']*')|[^>\s]+))?)*)\s*(\/?)>/)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }, "* Please remove all HTML from your comment and resubmit");

    $("#feedBackForm").validate(
        {
            rules: {
                Comment: {
                    required: true,
                    hasNoHTML: true
                }
            }
        }
    );
```

Here is the reference to the regular expression: http://ejohn.org/files/htmlparser.js

And the css to decorate the error:

```
.error {
    color:red;
}
```